# How to convert the numpy.ndarray data to required image format?

Tags: python, image, numpy-ndarray

I have a data in numpy.ndarray format e.g [45 42 35 ... 53 29 31](1x3072 numpy array of uint8s) which row of the array stores a 32x32 colour image. The first 1024 entries contain the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue.

I want to convert that ndarray image to 32x32 color image in jpg format.
Tried many options but seems valid/proper image is not created.

Any suggestion to convert the image into 32x32 shape?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img_data=[45 42 35 ... 53 29 31] 
data_2 = np.resize(img_data,(32,32,3))
img = Image.fromarray(data_2,'RGB')
img.save('./my.png')
```

Comment: Have you tried shape `(3, 32, 32)`? You probably have your data in *channels first* format

Comment: Yes, Tried, but the image is not visible and seems only one horizontal line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img_data=[45 42 35 ... 53 29 31] 
data_2 = np.swapaxes(np.resize(img_data,(3,32,32)),0, 2)
img = Image.fromarray(data_2,'RGB')
img.save('./my.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working and created a valid image, but only one issue just need to rotate one time to the right side. then it is perfect.

Comment: Are you able to do this same reconstruction for embeddings? Please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73117356/python-imagededupe-can-you-reconstruct-an-original-image-from-its-embeddings