# python imagededupe can you reconstruct an original image from its embeddings?

Tags: numpy, opencv, duplicates, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am using [imagededupe](https://github.com/idealo/imagededup) in Python to produce image embeddings I place in a folder and I want to take those embeddings and convert them back to the original .jpg image.

I encode each image by using the `CNN` method (*convolutional neural network trained on `ImageNet`*) method that package.

The resulting encodings are `numpy.ndarray` type, like so:

```
{'IMG-7817.jpg': array([0.        , 0.8666797 , 0.6738928 , ..., 0.19499177, 0.19915162,
        0.11766607], dtype=float32)}
```

To persist them in memory, I have used `numpy.ndarray.tolist()` to convert the `ndarray` values into a list of `floats`. Then it saves it as a new document into MongoDB.

Here is an example of one document, showing the floats:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('62de157cd66e524858266e56'),
 'filename': 'image_0.jpg',
 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 21, 0, 58, 297000),
 'encoding': [0.34322163462638855,
  0.509546160697937,
  0.5979495048522949,
  0.0,
  0.9418766498565674,
  0.062201134860515594,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.3629385828971863,
  0.8452704548835754,
  1.0556049346923828,
  0.15479359030723572,
  0.05965745821595192,
  0.6355874538421631,
  0.0075227259658277035,
  0.0,
  0.7630028128623962,
  0.25163599848747253,
  0.38510754704475403,
  0.05900629609823227,
  1.259505033493042,
  0.2511945962905884,
  0.34552499651908875,
  0.0,
  0.20837950706481934,
  0.0,
  0.46649169921875,
  0.04043807461857796,
  0.04735632985830307,
  2.764833450317383,
  0.28932467103004456,
  0.022755710408091545,
  1.7064937353134155,
  0.020368073135614395,
  0.08486563712358475,
  0.08789866417646408,
  0.018082227557897568,
  0.8046256899833679,
  0.2572726905345917,
  1.7080179452896118,
  0.13402247428894043,
  0.0,
  0.6671139597892761,
  0.6578285694122314,
  0.8306216597557068,
  0.33851000666618347,
  0.8741984367370605,
  1.769014596939087,
  0.684082567691803,
  0.5945196747779846,
  0.0,
  0.4923103153705597,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.43480363488197327,
  0.0,
  2.0243093967437744,
  3.1641061305999756,
  0.04148351401090622,
  0.2754305601119995,
  0.24396584928035736,
  0.0,
  0.02952236868441105,
  1.3269319534301758,
  0.400570809841156,
  0.1814577877521515,
  1.0266987085342407,
  0.0,
  0.48076146841049194,
  0.31500837206840515,
  0.24837727844715118,
  0.0,
  0.23274537920951843,
  0.10061652213335037,
  0.5313457250595093,
  0.22604097425937653,
  0.11777201294898987,
  0.6426587700843811,
  0.30787965655326843,
  0.00855748075991869,
  0.011529005132615566,
  1.1762546300888062,
  0.02678094431757927,
  1.6777329444885254,
  0.6672563552856445,
  0.23667019605636597,
  0.49905094504356384,
  0.9757379293441772,
  0.07683343440294266,
  1.5291916131973267,
  0.0,
  0.3130893409252167,
  0.6051976084709167,
  0.017192933708429337,
  0.43943557143211365,
  0.2320941686630249,
  0.3049321174621582,
  1.4164737462997437,
  3.0678188800811768,
  0.027480242773890495,
  0.0016468112589791417,
  0.0,
  0.07514918595552444,
  0.43065083026885986,
  3.375669479370117,
  1.547513723373413,
  0.4367760121822357,
  0.004104389809072018,
  0.19813460111618042,
  0.0,
  1.5236296653747559,
  2.4143331050872803,
  0.0,
  0.4325718879699707,
  0.3500346839427948,
  0.7155059576034546,
  0.0,
  2.191272258758545,
  0.021950488910079002,
  0.6380945444107056,
  0.07029495388269424,
  0.9965856075286865,
  0.7871404886245728,
  0.020270364359021187,
  0.21629869937896729,
  0.22851204872131348,
  0.6256837844848633,
  0.6793181896209717,
  0.0,
  0.7013466358184814,
  0.2701347768306732,
  0.4660792052745819,
  0.0,
  0.99172443151474,
  0.05413336679339409,
  0.9221435785293579,
  0.0,
  0.9360405802726746,
  0.0,
  0.030728023499250412,
  0.022367192432284355,
  0.019651522859930992,
  0.4800198972225189,
  0.11290711909532547,
  0.0,
  0.8062187433242798,
  0.0,
  0.7398870587348938,
  0.6118819713592529,
  0.17569033801555634,
  0.6082322597503662,
  0.025949034839868546,
  1.804274559020996,
  0.4318274259567261,
  0.0,
  0.33641141653060913,
  1.38775634765625,
  0.0,
  1.2272226810455322,
  0.15384995937347412,
  1.5630751848220825,
  1.190468192100525,
  0.5651965737342834,
  1.4905359745025635,
  0.08070334792137146,
  0.099326491355896,
  1.6428868770599365,
  1.8835887908935547,
  1.900753378868103,
  0.0058065494522452354,
  0.7904874682426453,
  0.7456177473068237,
  1.5191725492477417,
  0.0,
  1.411240577697754,
  0.0,
  0.2351973056793213,
  0.47451984882354736,
  0.6398224830627441,
  0.06026613339781761,
  0.06863820552825928,
  0.33046841621398926,
  1.8896198272705078,
  0.021269584074616432,
  2.3213772773742676,
  0.19969674944877625,
  0.22938404977321625,
  0.138387069106102,
  0.0,
  0.2955643832683563,
  0.7730927467346191,
  1.2605562210083008,
  1.813166618347168,
  0.5475223064422607,
  0.07392473518848419,
  0.05272753909230232,
  1.260231375694275,
  0.0,
  1.3669939041137695,
  0.13212966918945312,
  0.0,
  1.810328722000122,
  0.0,
  0.968720555305481,
  0.5265544056892395,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.3666769862174988,
  0.6280245780944824,
  0.24455592036247253,
  0.05917458236217499,
  0.1274377703666687,
  0.24018031358718872,
  0.04338640719652176,
  0.6593717336654663,
  0.4561670124530792,
  0.6908249258995056,
  0.0,
  0.025656165555119514,
  1.4662184715270996,
  0.4808516204357147,
  0.48574984073638916,
  0.0,
  0.5596708059310913,
  0.0,
  0.07661600410938263,
  0.8362483382225037,
  0.019625132903456688,
  1.4666523933410645,
  0.0,
  0.5307647585868835,
  0.2795000374317169,
  0.14065083861351013,
  0.06074102967977524,
  0.5063194036483765,
  0.3797137141227722,
  0.37272703647613525,
  0.22654202580451965,
  1.655469298362732,
  0.0,
  0.11777283996343613,
  1.388221263885498,
  0.327331006526947,
  0.14950616657733917,
  2.0307371616363525,
  0.40243691205978394,
  1.0219730138778687,
  1.53922438621521,
  1.2161401510238647,
  0.7625423073768616,
  0.1292436718940735,
  0.9063143134117126,
  0.9079506397247314,
  0.37720248103141785,
  1.4248236417770386,
  1.437509298324585,
  0.6693912148475647,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0027586750220507383,
  0.9666323065757751,
  0.0,
  0.46942809224128723,
  1.44985032081604,
  0.34272393584251404,
  2.2227885723114014,
  0.0,
  1.488860011100769,
  0.2924092411994934,
  1.0731092691421509,
  1.4170044660568237,
  0.10373884439468384,
  0.12016452103853226,
  0.02246188558638096,
  0.9552142024040222,
  0.05175960808992386,
  0.9273093342781067,
  0.4393492639064789,
  0.3075776696205139,
  0.2306509166955948,
  0.0,
  0.615312933921814,
  0.16303738951683044,
  0.0,
  0.2877673804759979,
  1.501681923866272,
  0.4097016751766205,
  2.9622018337249756,
  0.5579401254653931,
  0.142703577876091,
  0.5920137166976929,
  1.303241491317749,
  0.00606588926166296,
  0.4949913024902344,
  0.19190119206905365,
  0.733661413192749,
  0.6974300742149353,
  0.0,
  0.8278228044509888,
  0.5845810770988464,
  0.026461739093065262,
  0.4288907051086426,
  0.21419385075569153,
  2.954052686691284,
  0.3760499656200409,
  0.004199077375233173,
  3.8070878982543945,
  0.715491771697998,
  0.4648321568965912,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.19548028707504272,
  0.48019057512283325,
  1.1979873180389404,
  0.07732359319925308,
  0.19149938225746155,
  0.1502079963684082,
  2.0691733360290527,
  2.4982733726501465,
  1.337972640991211,
  1.100319504737854,
  2.6857542991638184,
  0.29503199458122253,
  0.23128174245357513,
  0.0,
  0.5455896854400635,
  0.4850095510482788,
  0.10392599552869797,
  0.2443435788154602,
  0.7817987203598022,
  0.0,
  2.063075065612793,
  0.4417440593242645,
  0.2553230822086334,
  0.3762524724006653,
  0.05001183599233627,
  0.04212421923875809,
  1.286272644996643,
  0.9305449724197388,
  0.02449200674891472,
  1.2230279445648193,
  0.0,
  0.29419076442718506,
  0.008204713463783264,
  0.7008044123649597,
  0.16965098679065704,
  0.11801895499229431,
  0.8991751670837402,
  0.4699343144893646,
  0.0,
  0.8951627612113953,
  1.3787250518798828,
  0.0,
  0.08008038997650146,
  1.3252822160720825,
  0.32005879282951355,
  0.0,
  0.4818739593029022,
  0.4019497334957123,
  0.7889391779899597,
  0.0,
  0.18576571345329285,
  0.0,
  1.3088619709014893,
  2.7723488807678223,
  0.00022756097314413637,
  0.4293895363807678,
  0.5022754073143005,
  0.044507503509521484,
  1.5894511938095093,
  0.062480755150318146,
  0.0,
  1.1833703517913818,
  1.6038163900375366,
  1.7601900100708008,
  0.11935224384069443,
  0.0,
  3.55781888961792,
  0.9694040417671204,
  0.38496172428131104,
  0.09860406816005707,
  1.0045870542526245,
  3.0407869815826416,
  1.3872655630111694,
  0.5597723722457886,
  0.4029926359653473,
  1.82244873046875,
  1.4435524940490723,
  0.0,
  0.268917053937912,
  1.1448471546173096,
  1.3053370714187622,
  0.6695809364318848,
  0.22877833247184753,
  0.8759015202522278,
  0.009998252615332603,
  0.22522638738155365,
  0.0,
  2.089116096496582,
  0.10225784778594971,
  0.0835852101445198,
  0.04399365931749344,
  0.357903391122818,
  0.00423638429492712,
  2.197624444961548,
  1.4854577779769897,
  0.785973310470581,
  0.0,
  1.33061945438385,
  0.05213224142789841,
  0.0,
  1.4183796644210815,
  0.07906366884708405,
  0.27266740798950195,
  0.0919405072927475,
  0.32426464557647705,
  1.0865753889083862,
  0.0,
  0.17555345594882965,
  0.8236625790596008,
  0.5672846436500549,
  0.0,
  0.035536810755729675,
  0.7000375986099243,
  1.5232492685317993,
  0.3168185353279114,
  0.0,
  0.29834094643592834,
  0.20520535111427307,
  0.4351038336753845,
  0.13560494780540466,
  0.48883458971977234,
  0.02037435956299305,
  1.1522188186645508,
  0.9122401475906372,
  0.0,
  1.30799400806427,
  0.22012335062026978,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.24422557651996613,
  0.0,
  0.4273641109466553,
  0.5228200554847717,
  0.5666704773902893,
  0.3363366425037384,
  0.6759360432624817,
  2.0034751892089844,
  0.17202824354171753,
  0.2595841884613037,
  0.015393995679914951,
  0.04131931811571121,
  0.18808656930923462,
  0.0669889822602272,
  0.9347860217094421,
  1.5079140663146973,
  2.3521738052368164,
  0.45415419340133667,
  0.7850313186645508,
  0.010190464556217194,
  0.6210658550262451,
  0.3110385835170746,
  0.08557576686143875,
  0.2882275879383087,
  0.018340876325964928,
  0.08235052973031998,
  0.11521648615598679,
  2.253997564315796,
  1.2350491285324097,
  0.08332804590463638,
  0.1232355460524559,
  2.3126087188720703,
  1.156542181968689,
  0.6510205864906311,
  0.0,
  0.12935137748718262,
  0.0308428592979908,
  0.3024436831474304,
  0.0,
  0.3228701055049896,
  1.1835720539093018,
  1.2879806756973267,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  1.0283877849578857,
  0.9930158257484436,
  0.46817547082901,
  1.4385830163955688,
  1.4435007572174072,
  0.3171677887439728,
  0.6235666871070862,
  0.5815529823303223,
  0.5360093116760254,
  0.9516975283622742,
  0.1696314960718155,
  0.09518808126449585,
  0.030107799917459488,
  0.31380897760391235,
  0.0,
  0.42714065313339233,
  0.5804895162582397,
  0.9608817100524902,
  0.1775510311126709,
  0.010171392001211643,
  0.5893941521644592,
  1.5398626327514648,
  0.39006567001342773,
  0.32146579027175903,
  2.948575019836426,
  0.06686578691005707,
  1.531951904296875,
  0.0,
  0.17576193809509277,
  0.2349756807088852,
  0.9275945425033569,
  0.3193134367465973,
  3.367725372314453,
  0.8526585102081299,
  0.0,
  0.422979474067688,
  1.0967295169830322,
  1.4886173009872437,
  0.08168420940637589,
  1.9246219396591187,
  0.6297357082366943,
  0.6322764158248901,
  0.0,
  2.65885329246521,
  1.6137109994888306,
  0.791668176651001,
  0.18871046602725983,
  1.6689802408218384,
  0.219522163271904,
  1.7474461793899536,
  0.10053602606058121,
  0.6737263798713684,
  0.8441563248634338,
  0.3114991784095764,
  0.7566099166870117,
  0.2245187759399414,
  0.2011154741048813,
  0.8214294910430908,
  0.0,
  1.9816653728485107,
  0.7716283798217773,
  1.6154274940490723,
  0.22172033786773682,
  0.0,
  0.058957479894161224,
  1.076833963394165,
  0.26426446437835693,
  1.0176373720169067,
  0.3910500705242157,
  2.1494927406311035,
  0.664349377155304,
  0.7940111756324768,
  0.4397018253803253,
  0.7703667283058167,
  0.0,
  0.018988996744155884,
  0.5460900664329529,
  1.7279266119003296,
  0.754666805267334,
  0.08635308593511581,
  0.5351725816726685,
  0.015438989736139774,
  0.5810871720314026,
  0.4795708954334259,
  0.09397150576114655,
  1.8130183219909668,
  1.0192855596542358,
  0.7982662916183472,
  0.6442264914512634,
  1.0579023361206055,
  0.9965284466743469,
  0.33102571964263916,
  0.0,
  0.12347199022769928,
  0.0012085589114576578,
  0.0,
  0.012317202985286713,
  0.7999298572540283,
  0.23033346235752106,
  0.10711371153593063,
  0.055289968848228455,
  0.10045799612998962,
  0.2694406807422638,
  1.6767593622207642,
  0.08160638809204102,
  0.055825188755989075,
  0.35727065801620483,
  0.14833365380764008,
  0.03880086913704872,
  0.05746801570057869,
  0.023325448855757713,
  0.3614659309387207,
  1.1203327178955078,
  0.23827773332595825,
  0.1701105833053589,
  0.005051849409937859,
  0.014566520228981972,
  0.0,
  0.17170780897140503,
  0.0,
  0.3361126184463501,
  0.7800708413124084,
  1.4469071626663208,
  0.9698413014411926,
  0.47699087858200073,
  0.0,
  0.6676139235496521,
  2.3889882564544678,
  0.16141292452812195,
  0.549674928188324,
  1.446986198425293,
  2.9572486877441406,
  1.2994608879089355,
  0.9938348531723022,
  0.012836528941988945,
  0.5091323852539062,
  0.3293815851211548,
  0.2696889638900757,
  0.023653989657759666,
  0.9666279554367065,
  0.0,
  0.09485077112913132,
  0.21621057391166687,
  0.05144309997558594,
  0.7748975157737732,
  0.16373832523822784,
  0.32590582966804504,
  3.2590131759643555,
  0.18453021347522736,
  0.32559701800346375,
  0.01810051128268242,
  1.3126763105392456,
  0.9643300771713257,
  0.7701171636581421,
  0.012872778810560703,
  3.2080838680267334,
  1.3774534463882446,
  0.6093534827232361,
  0.4270886778831482,
  1.536228060722351,
  1.0596519708633423,
  0.7293568849563599,
  0.040961820632219315,
  0.8098430037498474,
  0.03354305401444435,
  0.3781156837940216,
  0.07808584719896317,
  1.5445245504379272,
  0.2643190026283264,
  0.03979670628905296,
  0.1401960253715515,
  0.0,
  2.858400821685791,
  1.5187857151031494,
  0.916731059551239,
  0.4406169056892395,
  2.0909416675567627,
  0.041937537491321564,
  0.26336491107940674,
  0.6905952095985413,
  0.5504804849624634,
  0.7093060612678528,
  0.0,
  1.5680856704711914,
  0.6002225875854492,
  0.6944994926452637,
  0.09715773910284042,
  0.37384095788002014,
  0.09308439493179321,
  0.11243189871311188,
  0.0,
  0.0014087663730606437,
  0.6081674695014954,
  1.0300709009170532,
  0.0,
  1.6597859859466553,
  0.0,
  0.06655865907669067,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.776603102684021,
  0.706895112991333,
  0.06840622425079346,
  0.01103916671127081,
  0.20892217755317688,
  0.06662453711032867,
  2.3237693309783936,
  0.0,
  1.001037836074829,
  0.7960761189460754,
  0.011129717342555523,
  0.04408513754606247,
  0.9169716835021973,
  0.18723581731319427,
  0.0,
  0.13618384301662445,
  0.1143331304192543,
  0.08429567515850067,
  0.5295025706291199,
  0.24401012063026428,
  0.4518049657344818,
  1.6427943706512451,
  2.9292097091674805,
  0.2356298565864563,
  1.886139988899231,
  0.8494397401809692,
  1.0584583282470703,
  0.10908976197242737,
  1.6228749752044678,
  0.03479631990194321,
  0.3667331635951996,
  0.29944977164268494,
  0.0,
  0.5278289318084717,
  1.8577454090118408,
  0.7919538617134094,
  0.3287472724914551,
  1.0173267126083374,
  0.21281661093235016,
  2.5687320232391357,
  0.0,
  0.22931823134422302,
  0.08953932672739029,
  1.8022074699401855,
  0.031096210703253746,
  0.0,
  0.3735235929489136,
  0.9747275710105896,
  1.4670822620391846,
  0.0014497002121061087,
  0.1918376237154007,
  0.017492996528744698,
  0.14093568921089172,
  2.4359452724456787,
  1.0266388654708862,
  0.06744030863046646,
  0.5923642516136169,
  0.05829468369483948,
  0.7882423996925354,
  0.006824888754636049,
  0.0,
  0.12467359006404877,
  0.0,
  0.6454435586929321,
  0.7348983287811279,
  0.21230670809745789,
  0.751591682434082,
  0.10542069375514984,
  2.747696876525879,
  0.025314131751656532,
  1.5147247314453125,
  0.4253242611885071,
  0.026335788890719414,
  0.2820242941379547,
  0.0,
  1.629762887954712,
  0.0,
  1.0258194208145142,
  0.01697576977312565,
  0.0026492439210414886,
  0.5882153511047363,
  0.15281014144420624,
  0.15450280904769897,
  0.7614965438842773,
  1.5575156211853027,
  0.44215384125709534,
  0.031301699578762054,
  0.0,
  0.41315919160842896,
  0.0,
  0.9163169860839844,
  0.0,
  0.6567441821098328,
  2.000319480895996,
  0.6224666833877563,
  1.1936211585998535,
  0.37969183921813965,
  0.6791279315948486,
  0.7023849487304688,
  0.5725939273834229,
  0.33029961585998535,
  0.29946884512901306,
  0.08158722519874573,
  1.1009563207626343,
  0.1951158344745636,
  0.17529775202274323,
  0.0,
  0.24547788500785828,
  0.4813558757305145,
  0.10754260420799255,
  1.0999802350997925,
  0.09632908552885056,
  1.257835030555725,
  3.48246169090271,
  1.4914885759353638,
  1.3317164182662964,
  0.0,
  0.26352792978286743,
  0.1344657689332962,
  1.5231508016586304,
  0.10092543810606003,
  0.11918514966964722,
  2.744619846343994,
  0.0,
  1.9301466941833496,
  0.23720590770244598,
  1.2849202156066895,
  0.0021527463104575872,
  0.22261980175971985,
  0.0,
  1.2995405197143555,
  1.5964542627334595,
  0.3902784585952759,
  0.0,
  0.39399170875549316,
  1.5980095863342285,
  0.5178284049034119,
  1.002244472503662,
  0.0,
  1.0685653686523438,
  0.3623090386390686,
  0.24759413301944733,
  2.319288969039917,
  0.06726662069559097,
  0.4107389748096466,
  0.25172483921051025,
  0.09692853689193726,
  0.36315271258354187,
  0.19497661292552948,
  0.19528783857822418,
  0.9833536744117737,
  0.0,
  0.3592410981655121,
  0.3673408031463623,
  0.9627466797828674,
  0.026713738217949867,
  0.6547496318817139,
  0.04448238015174866,
  0.008870258927345276,
  0.6792797446250916,
  0.0,
  0.024829436093568802,
  1.5601677894592285,
  0.18391843140125275,
  0.16963115334510803,
  0.49852055311203003,
  0.29731711745262146,
  1.5001922845840454,
  0.5966616868972778,
  0.5658796429634094,
  0.9493252635002136,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.4046423137187958,
  1.4287112951278687,
  0.0,
  0.15436147153377533,
  0.3651731312274933,
  0.0,
  0.00114287412725389,
  0.4599761962890625,
  0.13904592394828796,
  0.049609310925006866,
  0.04458696022629738,
  0.006772597320377827,
  0.050582993775606155,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  1.1677778959274292,
  0.3135088384151459,
  0.1667020320892334,
  1.4050168991088867,
  0.08352083712816238,
  1.5827399492263794,
  1.193649172782898,
  0.030835293233394623,
  0.0,
  0.0015767943114042282,
  0.7566667795181274,
  0.26073670387268066,
  1.8150725364685059,
  0.0028364635072648525,
  0.7325196266174316,
  0.21360227465629578,
  0.27992552518844604,
  0.9042648673057556,
  2.0153775215148926,
  0.26339706778526306,
  0.0,
  0.6202089190483093,
  0.10526447743177414,
  2.882450580596924,
  0.3095151484012604,
  0.0,
  0.637947142124176,
  0.5944535136222839,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  2.7035391330718994,
  0.7932912111282349,
  0.40263426303863525,
  1.382933497428894,
  0.5418493151664734,
  0.08483023196458817,
  0.7244842052459717,
  0.20402145385742188,
  0.27017006278038025,
  1.0310587882995605,
  0.0,
  0.26290374994277954,
  0.44489234685897827,
  0.0,
  0.10985265672206879,
  4.00398588180542,
  0.0,
  1.889216661453247,
  0.9396313428878784,
  0.5248347520828247,
  2.334782361984253,
  0.6514081358909607,
  0.021495413035154343,
  0.30265650153160095,
  0.0,
  0.11324827373027802,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.07938762754201889,
  0.00594561081379652,
  0.2369159758090973,
  0.3200414478778839,
  0.7243974804878235,
  0.07896162569522858,
  0.19521552324295044,
  0.017373599112033844,
  0.0,
  0.7747635245323181,
  0.0,
  3.0585978031158447,
  0.2982688248157501,
  0.006080341059714556,
  0.11861772835254669,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.4043075144290924,
  0.0,
  0.2331291139125824,
  0.05324462428689003,
  0.3905235528945923,
  0.49934008717536926,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.2706427276134491,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.02849772945046425,
  0.5065882802009583,
  1.5505584478378296,
  1.4176472425460815,
  0.830781102180481,
  0.6771125197410583,
  0.1085791289806366,
  0.43909430503845215,
  0.13297335803508759,
  1.5684330463409424,
  2.108699321746826,
  0.11001390963792801,
  0.4872213900089264,
  0.32524189352989197,
  0.0737423524260521,
  0.14409983158111572,
  0.9547043442726135,
  1.1935787200927734,
  0.16664843261241913,
  0.282832533121109,
  0.28268536925315857,
  0.19144511222839355,
  0.11462447047233582,
  0.5705850720405579,
  0.434655100107193,
  0.03162039443850517,
  0.8690363168716431,
  0.049061935395002365,
  2.015324592590332,
  0.01103197317570448,
  0.9478869438171387,
  0.0,
  0.7611132264137268,
  1.5938303470611572,
  0.41670796275138855,
  0.5746119618415833,
  0.6635866165161133,
  1.0752760171890259,
  0.06721699237823486,
  0.05494782701134682,
  0.396668016910553,
  ...],
 'updatedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 0, 33, 50, 36000)}
```

And so, I want to take those saved embeddings from MongoDB and convert them back to the original `.jpg` image.

**Can this be done?**

I have tried unsuccessfully the following before asking:

1. Took the embeddings list, passed it to np.array (converting it into ndarray), then tried to use Image.fromarray to generate the image.  Got a `ValueError: not enough image data`

code:

```
na = np.array( embeddings_doc['embeddings'] ) 
image = Image.fromarray(na.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image
```

2. Tried to use PIL Image to render an image but it ended up displaying an image with a single line (the embeddings no doubt but a single line is not what I am after)

Before trying keras, perhaps someone can advise a better way to regenerate the original image from encodings?

I'm not saving the image shape.  Should I?  Is that going to be needed or can that be *figured out* by python somehow?

Comment: why do you expect, that you can **reconstruct** an image from that ? it's impossible ! never meant to happen !

Comment: Deduplicator - is not for image encoding. The vector that network produces is actually embeddings that allow to compare images, not more.

Comment: @Hihikomori Ok how can you produce an original image from embeddings?  Can be done?  impossible?  Because there's this quote "Image embedding is a vector representation of an image in which images with similar motives have similar vector profiles." from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/image-analytics-for-everyone-image-embeddings-with-orange-7f0b91fa2ca2

Comment: @rom, again, that is about similarity, not reconstruction

Comment: again, not every encoding is meant to be decoded to the original. in this case, the distance between two such features is meaningful, not the features themselves

Comment: Ok I see.  Well, if you needed to reconstruct the original images from a vector representation, not this way, but another way, how would you do it?

Comment: You can use an Autoencoder (AE) or a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) to get the embedding.

Comment: @hellohawaii and this will also allow reconstructing of the original image?  Trying to save money on database space!  :)

Comment: @rom Of course, basically, you train a network that first encodes the image to a vector, and then decodes the vector to image. Reconstruction loss is used for training the network. Note that you need to store the weight of encoder in the network to recover the image from vector.

Comment: Could you explain what you try to achieve? Did you try to save images in compressed form in a database?

Comment: if you don't have an autoencoder, you could run the network backwards, pushing the feature vector backwards through the net (initialized with random activations), to generate **one plausible input** that would result in such a feature vector. the nature of feature vectors is that they're very condensed, so you will not get back your input image, only something that would fit the same description. -- this "backwards inference" is a lot more difficult than simply feeding forward through an autoencoder.

Comment: @rom Please edit your question, that you need just store somehow image in database possibly with compression, or make a statement that restoring of image from embeddings is the only way that solves the problem.

Comment: @hellohawaii please consider posting your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: You can use an Autoencoder (AE) or a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) to get the embedding.

Image compression using nerual network is a more general research topic, which I am not familiar with. If you are interested, you can visit [paper with code](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-compression/latest#papers-list) and read some survey papers, like [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165168421003832). Perhpas you can try some SOTA method.

However, as you want a encoder of images *in your dataset* instead of a universial encoder that applies to *arbitrary images*, you may "overfit" on your dataset (it seems that you don't care about generalizability) and get a much shorter embedding than the standard image compression method.

Ideally, as overfitting is acceptable, I think you can assign a random vector embedding of each image, and force the network(decoder) to reconstruct corresponding images(decode the random embedding). This is like forcing network to "remember" all of the image.

The above method can be improved. You can also use an encoder to encode images to vectors and a decoder to decode the vectors to images. In this way the embedding is "learnable", and the network(encoder) may learn to store some useful information of original images in the embedding, which makes reconstruction easier. For example, all the images of faces may be close to each other in the embedding space. Equipped with a learnable encoder, the decoder network can be more lightweight (the encoder is facing a easier task!).

So in conclustion, I think any encoder-decoder style network with a reconstruction loss is fine. The simplest solution will be using an Autoencoder (AE) or a Variational Autoencoder (VAE). For the decoder I think you can even use all kinds of generative model, like GAN, flow based models, diffustion model(but diffustion models may be unsuitable for compression).

---

**Why your original attempt fails:**

You may be confused about the meaning of "encode"/"decode" in neural network. It is different from "encode a string to bytes, and decode the bytes back to string". Also, it is not the same as "convert an image to numpy array and convert the numpy array back to image".

You may also misunderstand meaning of "embedding" produced by the neural network.  In fact, "embedding" is a terminology used in deep learning. Generally, you feed a input to the network, and any "feature map"(intermediate results produced by the network) can be considered as an embedding.

Usually, the embedding you get is dependent on the task that the network is designed to do. For example, the embedding from CNN trained on ImageNet is good for classification (all images of faces may have similar embeddings, all images of flowers have similar embeddings which are different from face embeddings). But these embeddings are not suitable for reconstruction(It may lost the detailed information, only the high-level semantic info like "what object is inside the image"). If you want an embedding that preserves some property, choose a network that do related tasks and pick embeddings from it. Since you want a compression embedding that you can reconstruct images from, choose a network that trained with reconstruction loss (the CNN you used is a classification loss)!

Answer (score 2):

The embeddings means following:

Assume there is a neural network that gives 3-component vector like `[1,0,0]`.

`[1,0,0]` -there is only a cat on the image.

`[0,1,0]` -there is only a dog on the image.

`[0,0,1]` -there is only a human on the image.

Assume we have a vector `[0.7,0.2,0.5]`, this means:

70% chance that there is a cat on image, 20% chance there is a dog and 50% there is a human.

Since we know such vectors for images, we can compare them in this terms.

**WARNING !!! THE FOLLOWING METHOD IS GIVEN ONLY TO EXPLAIN WHY IT IS NOT GOOD IDEA TO USE EMBEDDINGS FOR IMAGE STORING. TREAT "BLUR" AS AN OPERATION WHICH PROVIDES THE CERTAIN PROBABILITY OF OBJECT DETECTION.**

The reconstruction of image by this vector can be done in following way:

1. Create a dataset of 3 images - cat,dog and human.
2. Blur each image for some amount to provide certain probability.
3. Then each blurred image place to it's specific predefined position on resulting image.

By constructing image this way it is possible make image for each possible embeddings.

Let us change the images in the dataset. For the same embeddings there will be the other image. We can add some background, so we will get another image for our embeddings. So for one embeddings vector there is infinite variety of different images.

This method solves the reconstruction problem, but reconstruction result is useless for most cases. That shows that embeddings can not store image data.

Networks like `imagededupe` works the same way, but they have more features and features means something else.

The embeddings vector is similar to verbal description of image (in some way).

There are networks like `Dall-E` that generates images from verbal description, so theoretically it is possible to generate image by embeddings. But I didn't see the claim that `Dall-E` can be applied for image compression.

Image can be encoded in `jpg` and represented as `bytes` type. It can be decoded later with `cv2.decode`

```
import cv2

{'IMG-7817.jpg':Binary(cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes())}
```

Comment: that's completely missing the question, which was about generating an image from a feature vector.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz "save an image to a format which can be saved in MongoDB " - this is a part of question, and I gave the answer.

Comment: The contributor already can obtain and save embeddings. Since it is impossible to decode image from embeddings, the only way to store a pair: image as jpg and embeddings vector.

Comment: the _bounty_ extends this question to be *multiple questions*, without stating that *in the question itself.* it ought to be closed for lack of focus now. a partial answer is better than nothing but if you apply that logic to other questions, you can easily pick and choose which "part" of a question to answer so the answer completely misses the point, as I said. I would not recommend posting answers because you want the points. answer have to address the question itself. -- storing a file in a database is fairly trivial. if OP were truly asking that, they weren't doing their research.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are being too straight forward. What I posted doesn't answers the question the way it was written, but it can solves the contributors problem finally.

Comment: OP's often asks about trivial things, I guess it is a case.

Comment: you're just making it worse. you can't just take a bunch of images, average them, and expect something sensible to result from that. that works for faces, where the faces are aligned so the eyes are always in the same position. it does not work for objects with more variation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I didn't say anything about aligning images, and I didn't propose to do that. This is an explanation why it is impossible to reconstruct the image form embeddings.

Comment: my point was that *"The reconstruction of image by this vector can be done if we just take the images of cat, dog and human, blur them in corresponding percentage and place it in a frame"* won't even produce a *sensible* or *classifiable* image. it'll just be a blur. it may be halfway recognizable if you use _one_ instance of each class, but that choice would be arbitrary, and given these embedding vectors are at least 1000 elements large, and they are *not* one-hot class labels but *feature vectors*, you'd get a superposition of 1000 different images, more or less.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz As I said "I didn't propose to do that". It is said that dealing such way is "useless". I am trying to give explanation in simple words that corresponds OP level. The example of the image reconstruction way was given to show that it is a bad idea.

Comment: added word "separately", so result is not superposition.

Comment: still not making a difference. there is no conceivable interpretation of "separately" that improves the situation. you propose to blur something, which I assumed means blending, not blurring (because blurring makes the situation worse), and if you blend, then you need multiple things, not separate things.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I meant blurring. Blurring of the cat must reduce the probability of it's detection. By placing objects separately in image and  blurring them for corresponding amount it is possible make NN applied on this image provide any possible vector.

Comment: blurring, say with a gaussian kernel, has a "sigma" or radius parameter, but *not* a "percentage" parameter. by whatever value and in whatever way you blur a picture, a neural net trying to classify the image will generally _not_ respond to that _linearly_, not even remotely linearly. -- the classification of a composite image will still very likely give _one_ of the classes the clear majority of the "probability mass". do not expect this to be additive. examine the formula for softmax. that entire suggestion is implausible.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Critics of methods details would be useful if it was a post about method. But this is an attempt to explain what is "embeddings" for OP in simple words. But thanks for comments. They helped to make post better.

Comment: you haven't actually demonstrated that some semblance of the original image couldn't be recovered from such a vector. you only showed that one specific idea doesn't work. that doesn't prove anything. OP shows that his embedding vectors are fairly long so they can hold enough information to make it plausible. the only issue is *how* the network was trained. if it was trained as an autoencoder, the activations taken from the narrow middle part of the network would encode information such that the image could be recovered fairly well. don't be so motivated by that 50 rep.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Just look honestly on situation: OP wanted to store image data and embeddings vector to database. By lack of experience he decided that embeddings can be converted to image with `PIL` lib. The given answer shows the way to save image in database. "regenerate the original image from encodings" - doesn't mean "restoring images by embedding vector" because of context. So, the other discussion "completely missing the question". But if you insist, image generation with NN works for limited cases. For example, if I want to render some object from different views.

Comment: "motivated by that 50 rep" - that is your fantasy. I taking a position that this question must be read not formally in OP's interests.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up taking MongoDB documents containing the image URL links, downloading those images to disc, storing images in a MongoDB GridFS collection in an optimized way, deleting the images, then taking the _id of that collection's doc and putting it onto the original doc as a key "gridfs_id'.  That solved the issue of compression/storage for me.  I then took the embeddings and stored them in an array of objects with the imageUrl as key and numpy embeddings stored as array of floats.  I was able to reconstruct the embeddings and run imagededupe duplicate across multiple images now.